# Validation error - Function name must be a string

Tags: laravel

I have a custom rule ValidateID and I have this code to use the rule:

```
    public function store(Request $request, $id, $slug = null, Validator $validator){

    $rules = [];
    $messages = [];

    $rules["name"] = 'required|max:255|string';

    $rules([
        "ID" =>['required', 'string', new ValidateID()]
    ]);
}
```

But it appears the error below, do you know why?

```
{message: "Function name must be a string",…}exception
message:"Function name must be a string"
```

Comment: You're using `$rules` array as a function here: `$rules([ "ID" =>['required', 'string', new ValidateID()] ]);`, that's invalid syntax

Comment: Thanks, do you know how to correct the issue?

Comment: Assign it the same way you did for the `$rules["name"]`